# Spring boot - h2 and Oracle no 100% compatibility

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, h2, flyway

I am using `H2` in Spring boot app and `Oracle DB` on production. 
For checking migration files I use FlyWay. 
Unfortunately, H2 isn't compatible with Oracle (even if is set Oracle mode).
So, I can't validate my migrations files. 
When I have a H2 query - validation in my project is ok, but when I upload it to production - it won`t work on Oracle.
Have you got any ideas how can I validate oracle migration files on my h2-db project?

Comment: For example editing columns data types. On h2 sql : `ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;` and on oracle: `ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;`

Comment: By using Oracle. Different databases are generally not compatible if using anything outside of what is specified in the ANSI SQL spec.

Comment: We're currently working on resolving issues with Flyway and H2 in Oracle mode - watch out for FLyway 6.0.2

Answer (score 2):

The [Flyway FAQ](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#db-specific-sql) covers this under db specific SQL:

> You can use the flyway.locations property. It would look like this:
>
> ```
>    TEST (Derby): flyway.locations=sql/common,sql/derby
>    PROD (Oracle): flyway.locations=sql/common,sql/oracle
> ```
>
> You could then have the common statements (V1__Create_table.sql) in common and different copies of the DB-specific statements (V2__Alter_table.sql) in the db-specific locations.

Another approach if the differences are *really* minor ie only a few keywords, would be to have the keywords that differ as Flyway placeholders:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ${alter_column} COLUMN column_name datatype;

TEST (H2):     flyway.placeholders.alter_column=ALTER
PROD (Oracle): flyway.placeholders.alter_column=MODIFY
```